# Would like to use generic base class as model for asp.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel class foo that is a generic

```
public abstract class Base<T>
```

and its child types set the class when they inherit from it like this

```
public class Child : Base<Foo>
```

I would like to use them in a view as the model like

```
@model Base<T>
```

but i have heard this is not possible. I've seen people suggest putting dynamic in place of T, but that does not work unless i replace Foo with dynamic also. Is there any way to design the viewmodels like that? I suppose I could pass the Child object in the viewbag instead of the model, but i'd rather not do that if possible. EDIT: (that viewbag thing wouldn't actually work now that i think about it because i'd need to be able to cast it to a Base to use it as one, and that's basically the problem i'm having now)

Comment: I honesty don't know how the view would be able to access the model's elements when using generics, but I really want to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write in View `@model Base<T>` cause it is not concrete Type. View cannot be typed with generic Type. But you can write

```
@model Base<Foo>
```

or

```
@model Base<dynamic>
```

If you show more about what properties in `Base<T>` i could give you more concrete advise.

Comment: the properties would just be a List<T> and some regular types like ints. maybe a method that returns a List<T>

Comment: Why is it should be List<T>?  How it will be used in View? Is this view will be different for different T?

Comment: no it won't be dependent on T. it's just that Base is not a type

Comment: things that are internal to the Model. The only reason i was trying to specify T is because "Base" by itself is not a type and can't be used to declare the model. I was hoping the View object could be a generic underneath and allow a generic Model, but it seems like it can't